# Node js / javascript promises not waiting to finish the sequelize query

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am expecting the below promise to return customer and blox slot also as part of booking record in second .then(). But addCustomer and addBooking has not executed or yet to be executed.

when I added await in addBooking or addCustomer, it didnt work.

I am not sure where i am missing

```
const bookingCreated = await Booking.create(data).then((booking) => {
    const customers = data.customer_id;
    if (data.customer_id !== '') {
        customers.forEach((customer) => booking.addCustomer(customer, booking.id));
    }
    tempBoxSlots.forEach((slot) => boxSlotBooking.addBooking(slot, booking.id));
    return booking;
}).then((result) => {
    console.log('result');
    console.log(result.id);
    const boxSlotAttributes = ['id', 'start_time', 'duration'];
    const retBooking = Booking.findOne({
        where: {
            id: result.id
        },
        include: [{
                model: BookingType
            },
            {
                model: BookingSource
            },
            {
                model: Venue
            },
            {
                model: Customer,
                as: 'lead'
            },
            {
                model: BoxSlot,
                attributes: boxSlotAttributes,
                through: {
                    attributes: []
                }
            },
            {
                model: Customer,
                attributes: ['id', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'email'],
                through: {
                    attributes: []
                }
            }

        ]
    });

    return retBooking;
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
});
console.log('bookingCreated');
console.log(bookingCreated);
```

Comment: Which of your methods are asynchronous? What is `data`? What is `data.customer_id`? From its name I would not have expected you could do a `forEach` on it. Is it a standard array? What is `tempBoxSlots`?  Are `addCustomer`  and/or `addBooking` returning promises? ...etc.

Comment: data.customer_id is an array. data.customer_id = [3,4,5] and tempBoxSlots = [6,7,8]. addCustomer and addBooking is a sequelize functions, that adds associations to the database. I dont think, it will return promise.

Answer (score 0):

According to the examples given in [this sequalize documentation](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/associations/belongs-to-many.js%7EBelongsToMany.html), the methods that are automatically added when you define associations, like `add*`, return promises.

So instead of the `forEach` loops with `addCustomer` and `addBooking`, you would need to collect those promises (with `.map`) and pass those to `Promise.all`:

```
await Promise.all([...customers.map((customer) => booking.addCustomer(customer, booking.id)),
                   ...tempBoxSlots.map((slot) => boxSlotBooking.addBooking(slot, booking.id))]);
```

I would also replace all the `then` calls you have, with `await`. Go for one pattern: either `then` chaining, or `async/await`. But for readability, avoid the mix.

Another remark: the check `if (customer_id == '')` is a bit odd, because `customer_id` is an array, and so checking for an non-empty array is better done with `if (customer_id.length)`.
Moreover, there is no reason to exclude an empty array from executing what is in that `if` block, so you can actually do without that `if` condition all together.

Comment: Thats wonderful!! Exactly what i am looking for. But 2 more questions/clarifications from your answer. what ... (3 dots) exactly doe how map() is different from Foreach()?

Comment: `map` *returns* an array (with every value from original array "mapped" to a new value for the returned array), while `forEach` returns nothing. The `...` is called spread syntax (look it up). Instead of `[..., ...]`, you could also have used `customers.map().concat(tempBoxSlot.map())` (I left out the callbacks to `map` - those are needed of course)